# I am trying to implement the google sample code for wifi direct in android but it is giving me an exception

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

The demowifi project given [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F).

but when I try to implement it I get this error-

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: microsoft.demo_wifidirect, PID: 3540
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.wifi.p2p.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE flg=0x24000010 (has extras) } in microsoft.demo_wifidirect.WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver@41bad428
                                                                             at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:782)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5641)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1288)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1104)
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: microsoft.demo_wifidirect.DeviceListFragment cannot be cast to microsoft.demo_wifidirect.DeviceDetailFragment
                                                                             at microsoft.demo_wifidirect.WiFiDirectActivity.resetData(WiFiDirectActivity.java:101)
                                                                             at microsoft.demo_wifidirect.WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver.java:101)
                                                                             at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:772)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5641) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Please help me understand what went wrong as I am completely new to android.

Comment: try this link for demo: https://github.com/ahmontero/wifi-direct-demo

Comment: In `WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver` you are casting `DeviceListFragment` to `DeviceDetailFragment`, which is causing the error

Comment: add WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver class

Comment: You have changed the package name. Is is changed everythere, especially in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who had this issue, this cast exception was being thrown because I had both fragment classes listed as "DeviceDetailFragment": ) When I corrected it and ensured that one was for DeviceDetailFragment and the other was for DeviceDetailFragment as shown below, it worked fine.

https://github.com/hiteshbpatel/Android_Blog_Projects/blob/master/WiFiShareFilesExampleAndroid/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml

Also, props to Hitesh Patel for putting together a quick working version of this tech on GitHub: https://github.com/hiteshbpatel

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_weight="0.9">
    <fragment
        class="com.example.shriyanshu.wifisharefilesexampleandroid.DeviceListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/phone_list_height"
        tools:layout="@layout/device_list">
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        class="com.example.shriyanshu.wifisharefilesexampleandroid.DeviceDetailFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/device_detail">
    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```